# MySQL Select rows with specific revision, if not, return a LOWER revision

Tags: mysql, sql

For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Imagine I have a table with the following data:

```
| id | revision | deleted | passage
-------------------------------------
| 22 |        1 |       0 | O Romeo, Romeo, wherefore art thou Romeo?
| 22 |        2 |       0 | Oh Romeo, why are you a Montague??
| 22 |        3 |       0 | Yo Romeo, why you all bein a Montague up in here?
| 39 |        1 |       0 | Call me Ishmael
```

In this example, lets say I want all revision 2s.  Since there is no revision 2 for ID 39, I'll make due with revision 1.

```
| id | revision | deleted | passage
-------------------------------------
| 22 |        2 |       0 | Oh Romeo, why are you a Montague??
| 39 |        1 |       0 | Call me Ishmael
```

I've tried playing with 'MAX' queries with limits, but I couldn't seem to get it right.  I'm certain it's a simple trick I'm missing, but can't seem to find it.

The ID will remain the same if it's simply a different revision.  The PK is on id-revision.

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.revision = (select max(revision)
                    from table t2
                    where t2.id = t.id and
                          t2.revision <= 2
                   );
```